# USB Drive Malware (.lnk extension) Suspicions: Seeking Advice on Next Steps

Tags: malware, macos, usb-drive

I recently encountered a concerning situation involving a USB drive, and I'm seeking guidance on how to proceed.

**The scenario:**

I used an older computer to extract photos from a DVD and transferred them onto a USB drive. However, when I plugged this USB drive into my Mac, I noticed that all the files on it had been changed to .lnk extensions. In a moment of panic, I immediately removed the USB drive.
Additionally, I found a file called `njw0rm.exe.lnk`

Given my limited knowledge in information security, I'm hesitant to reinsert the USB drive and further examine its contents. I'm not sure how to properly handle this situation, and I'm concerned about the possibility of malware being involved.

Any recommendations and help on how to secure my Mac and if possible restore the data would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like this malware is targeted at Windows since it is using Windows shortcuts, so your mac should probably be fine. .lnks won't execute on it. You may want to run an up to date anti-virus on the older computer though.

Comment: I plugged the USB back in my mac, and it has a file called njw0r.exe.lnk which I think is supposed to be the malware.
It also seems that the USB's storage is still intact, could it be that the malware just hid the files? 
So maybe `attrib -s -r -h /s /d *.*` will restore the data?